# Как передать string в структуру по байтно в массив byte[] c#

Tags: c#, строки, структуры, byte

Подскажите, как передать в структуру в массив типа byte[] строку string, чтобы каждый символ был в отдельной ячейке памяти.
Структура:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0)]
    public struct FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 NextEntryOffset;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public Byte Flags;
        [FieldOffset(5)] public Byte EaNameLength;
        [FieldOffset(6)] public UInt16 EaValueLength;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public Byte[] EaName;
    }

    var eaName = "TEST";
    var te = "fjhskdjfhksjfh";
    uint nextEntryOffset = 0;
    var flags = 0;
    var tt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eaName + "\0" + te + "\0");
    FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION EASet = new FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION();
```

Заполнение структуры:

```
    EASet.NextEntryOffset = (byte)nextEntryOffset;
    EASet.Flags = (byte)flags;
    EASet.EaNameLength = (byte)eaName.Length;
    EASet.EaValueLength = (ushort)te.Length;
    EASet.EaName = tt;  // проблема именно в этой строке, как ее правильно заполнить. если делать как написано, то запишется только размер массива, но не его элементы.
```

Либо может быть есть способ присвоить этой структуре определенный буфер в памяти, может через Marshal. Сама задача в том, чтобы данная структура была записана последовательно.

Comment: Вам в структуру нужно ссылку записать на массив или сам массив разместить в структуре, подобно статическим массивам из `c`/`c++`?

Comment: мне нужно массив в структуре разместить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для размещения массива (а не ссылки на массив) в структуре необходимо использовать [буферы фиксированного размера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers).

В настройках проекта нужно разрешить компиляцию небезопасного кода, а структуру пометить ключевым словом `unsafe`:

```
public unsafe struct FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION
```

Само поле объявляется с ключевым словом `fixed`:

```
[FieldOffset(8)]
public fixed byte EaName[80];
```

Цифра `80` в коде выше - размер буфера, который будет размещен в структуре. Выбирайте его осторожно, так как если он будет слишком коротким, в него не поместится нужная вам информация, а если слишком длинным - то и размер структуры будет неоправданно большим.

Также было бы неплохо вынести это магическое число `80` в какую-нибудь константу и потом использовать в коде её, чтобы не менять это число в коде в нескольких местах каждый раз, когда у вас меняется размер буфера, например:

```
public const int EaNameLength = 80;
```

Теперь по поводу заполнения этого буфера:

```
var tt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eaName + "\0" + te + "\0");
unsafe
{
    // определяем фактическую длину содержимого буфера
    // если длина строки больше размера буфера, то она будет обрезана
    int bufferLength = Math.Min(80, tt.Length);
    // копируем содержимое tt в EASet.EaName
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
        EASet.EaName[i] = tt[i];
}
```

Чтение буфера осуществляется аналогичным образом - в небезопасном контексте и с использованием индексатора. Важно понимать, что буфер фиксированного размера - не то же самое, что и обычный массив. Массивы размещаются в управляемой куче, в то время как буферы последовательно встраиваются в типы значений.

Comment: огромное спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 0):

При маршалинге для массивов необходимо указывать их тип как UnmanagedType.ByValArray, а так же указать их точный размер. Даже если размер будет отличаться, при передаче он будет автоматически уравнен в необходимый. Пример:

```
[FieldOffset(8), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
public Byte[] EaName;
```